# Webstorm debugging with source maps from Browserify and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, browserify

My project is a Laravel site, and I have the public folder renamed to "html". So my public files look like:

```
html
--js
----main.ts
```

And `html` is technically the root of the site for debugging purposes.

Using browserify, I have now generated some source maps for bundle.js, which have paths for main.ts. The problem is that they are pointing to the full path:

```
"html/js/main.ts"
```

Usually, I can run configurations to the `html` folder and catch breakpoints.

```
http://myapp.app:8000 ->> project>html
```

But this is not hitting breakpoints, since the `html` folder doesn't really exist in this setup. What's strange is that I can set break points in Chrome tools and it works. How can I set up Webstorm so it will hit break points in the `html` folder?

EDIT:

I am using the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/rmartone/bba859b05e70de52e160) for my source maps.

```
/**
 * Browserify Typescript with sourcemaps that Webstorm can use.
 * The other secret ingredient is to map the source directory to the
 * remote directory through Webstorm's "Edit Configurations" dialog.
 */
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    tsify = require('tsify'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    buffer = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var config = {
    client: {
        outDir: './public/scripts',
        out: 'app.js',
        options: {
            browserify: {
                entries: './src/client/main.ts',
                extensions: ['.ts'],
                debug: true
            },
            tsify: {
                target: 'ES5',
                removeComments: true
            }
        }
    }
};

gulp.task('client', function () {
    return browserify(config.client.options.browserify)
        .plugin(tsify, config.client.options.tsify)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
        .pipe(source(config.client.out))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./', {includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '/scripts'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client.outDir));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it in Webstorm. The correct remote url for the html folder in run configurations is:

```
http://myapp.app:8000/js/html
```

Pretty weird, but Webstorm thinks that /js/html is a folder and that the source files are inside there.

**EDIT 1** :Let me edit this answer. It turns out that the snippet above wasn't giving me all of the source maps. When inspecting the map file, the sources were being listed as `js` files and not `ts` files, which meant that the debugger wouldn't catch break points.

Here is the working gulp task, which watches any Typescript file for changes (as long as it's a dependency of `main.ts` and triggers browserify and the new sourcemaps. It requires the [tsify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify) plugin.

```
'use strict';

var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var assign = require('lodash.assign');

// add custom browserify options here
var customOpts = {
    entries: ['./html/js/main.ts'],
    debug: true
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts));
gulp.task('bundle', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal
b.plugin('tsify')

function bundle() {
    return b.bundle()
        // log errors if they happen
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
        .pipe(buffer())
        // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // loads map from browserify file
        // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false, sourceRoot: './'})) // writes .map file
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./html/js'));
}
```